# FileSystem API: Where are the files and folders located

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-filesystem

I'm currently developing a chrome app and need to access local files and directorys. My question is when I create a file or folder where are they located?
The extension is currently in my home directory and the created files aren't in the extension directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file system API is "virtual" in that you cannot store the files entirely literally on the client's computer. You can only really access them via JavaScript.

Nevertheless, they are stored with different filenames in several directories (having non-intuitive names) in:

```
%appdata%\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\File System
```

Where `%appdata%` is e.g. `C:\Users\xxx\AppData` (on Vista).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I'm using Ubuntu and there the path is:
/home/username/.config/google-chrome/Default

Comment: @DominicBartl I know it's been a while, but that path doesn't appear to be used anymore.